# AWS s3 access PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, amazon-s3, certificate, pkix

I have a https enabled Spring Boot service which does access the AWS S3. Now this service maintains its own custom truststore. So I have exported the following certificate from Java cacerts and added to its custom truststore.

**Alias name:** amazonrootca1 [jdk],amazonrootca2 [jdk],amazonrootca3 [jdk],amazonrootca4 [jdk], starfieldclass2ca [jdk], starfieldrootg2ca [jdk], starfieldservicesrootg2ca [jdk]

But still getting the following issue

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: will keep in mind

Comment: How have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes, I imported the required certificate into my own trustore